# numpy @njit cannot determine Numba type of <class 'module'>

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numba

I have this function

```py
@njit
def generate_rays(image_width, image_height, viewport):
    #rays.shape = (#rays, 3)
    rays = np.empty((image_height * image_width, 3))
    for i in range(image_height):
        for j in range(image_width):
            rays[image_width * i + j] = viewport.lower_left + i/(image_height - 1) * viewport.vertical + j/(image_width-1 ) * viewport.horizontal
    return rays
```

which gives the following error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at REDACTED/ray.py
File "ray.py", line 7:
def generate_rays(image_width, image_height, viewport):
    <source elided>
    #rays.shape = (#rays, 3)
    rays = np.empty((image_height * image_width, 3))
    ^

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
 - argument 2: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'module'>
```

I tried specifying the dtype of rays as such:
`rays = np.empty((image_height * image_width, 3), dtype=np.float64)`
yet it still gives the same error. I really can't tell what `<class 'module'>` is referring to...

Comment: Are you sure image_height and image_weight values are integer ?

Comment: @ikibir yes. the arguments that are called on the function are all integer.

Comment: What is the object viewport? This likely causes the error. There are only some objects directly supported by Numba (eg. numpy nd-arrays)

Comment: @max9111 viewport is just a container class that just contains some constants that I use often.

Comment: Is it a Numba jitclass https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jitclass.html . Otherwise this wont work without object mode (which makes no sense for constants). Global variables are getting hardcoded in the function anyway.

Comment: @max9111 it is not. I wanted to change the values in the class later. I will try implementing the class with jitclass. Thank you

Comment: @max911 in the link I find `spec = [ ('value', int32),  ('array', float32[:])]` How would I set the type of `array` to an n-dimensional array of `float32`s? I believe this is only the 1-d case.

Comment: numpy nd-arrays can be a member of a jitclass. If they are not too many a simple solution would be to pass the scalars and arrays directly to the function. This would work out of the box.

Comment: sorry, how would I make them a member of a jitclass? How would I specify it as the argument to the decorator `jitclass` like shown in the link: `@jitclass(spec)`